# Using React and redux to build a browser extension

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, browser-extension

I'm building a fairly complex browser extension for a client and it occurred to me that I could leverage Redux in the backend scripts to simplify the overall information flow, as well as using React in the UI, and modern javascript in the content scripts I need.

I've got a basic extension working, by building the background and content scripts in separate build steps.  My `src` folder looks like:

```
src/
  background/
    index.js (and other js files)
  content/
    index.js (and other js files)
  toolbar/  (shows intro text and a button to display prefs - see webpage below)
    toolbar.html
    App.js
    App.css
    components/ (etc)
  webpage/  (displays the UI elements for use prefs etc)
    webpage.html
    App.js
    App.css
    components/ (etc)
  common/
    index.js (etc - common logic used by both toolbar, webpage, content and background.)
```

Right now I am building each subfolder independently via scripts in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf build",
    "build": "yarn build:app && yarn build:bg && && yarn build:cont",
    "build:app": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false react-scripts build",
    "build:bg": "webpack --mode production ./src/background --output ./build/background.js",
    "build:cont": "webpack --mode production ./src/content --output ./build/content.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

but the `build:app` step by default seems to also build everything that's in `src/` so the `background`, `content` etc stuff gets duplicated and the html in the subfolders is unused.

Is there a way to tell `create-react-app`'s webpack config to build these all to suit the needs of my extension without ejecting?

Comment: I would use something like https://github.com/jhen0409/react-chrome-extension-boilerplate. If you need some CRA features you could share code between CRA and boilerplate using symlinks.

Comment: Thanks - that's interesting but very out of date.